# Yii - no values are being retrieved from the MYSQL database

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I am new to Yii framwork in PHP. I had created a MySQL database using Python and populated it using python code. I have used the same database for Yii and created models and controllers for the table using Gii. I have opened the CRUD interface for listing the values ->

```
http://localhost/vawHack/index.php?r=AppName/admin
```

I am getting the message "No results found." and no values saved in the database is shown. Am I missing something in between?

Comment: Can you post the code for admin action ??

Comment: The actions and all were generated by gii itself.. Here is an example of actionView:

public function actionView($id)
 {
  $this->render('view',array(
   'model'=>$this->loadModel($id),
  ));
 }

Comment: public function actionAdmin()
 {
  $model=new VawHackAppDistrict('search');
  $model->unsetAttributes();  // clear any default values
  if(isset($_GET['VawHackAppDistrict']))
   $model->attributes=$_GET['VawHackAppDistrict'];

  $this->render('admin',array(
   'model'=>$model,
  ));
 }

Comment: Okiee in loadmodel function which model are you loading ?? post the code for loadmodel function

Comment: I am using VawHackAppDistrict as the model.

Comment: Do one thing you var_dump the result as shown 

$result=VawHackAppDistrict::model()->findByPk(4);//Give valid id from the database 
var_dump($result) see weather you get the content relevant to that id

Comment: Means you have no data in the database

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36230/discussion-between-sudip-kafle-and-ninad)